# Вывод содержимого строки как элемент html C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Допустим, у меня есть строка а:

```
string a = "<span>dddd</span>";
```

Как мне вывести содержимое строки "a" как элемент html?
(а точнее, как мне создать span элемент с содержимым при помощи строки?)

(сделать это нужно в файле .cshtml)

HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(a); не работает, выводится не то, что нужно.

Comment: `@Raw("<span>dddd</span>")`

Comment: Mark, а в Raw можно использовать просто имя переменной?

Comment: да, и имя переменной, и выражение.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает, плюсик вам в карму :)

Comment: Должно работать из коробки. Возможно, вам стоит искать ответ на вопрос, почему HtmlHelper не доступен из Razor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper

Comment: Mark, Html.Raw(string), я просто загуглил этот метод